# How to make IE to support -webkit-overflow-scrolling?

Tags: internet-explorer, webkit

I'm developing a Web app that will only be used within an internal system, using either an iPad or a large touch screen with IE10. I have some areas of content that I'd like to make scrollable using overflow: auto.

For the iPads, I can use -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch to bring in iOS-style scrolling to the content area – the main feature I want here is the ability to scroll the content up or down by touching anywhere in the content area (the same as you would scroll on any touch device). The iPads are perfect, but I'm having trouble finding an equivalent that will work in IE10. The normal scrollbar appears to the right of the content area in IE10, but this is a bit fiddly to use on a touch screen.

Does anyone know of a JavaScript solution that will replicate the functionality of -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch in IE10?

Answer (score 1):

Reference: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/css2/mobile.html

The above link is a compatibility chart for various mobile browser features across various platforms. The scrolling bits that are relevant to this question are at the bottom of the page.

Discussing the default scrolling quality for each platform, the author states:

> The point of this entry is that only those browsers that have bad default scrolling quality need `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch`.

He lists iOS has having bad default scrolling quality and IE10 as having good scrolling quality. Therefore (in the opinion of the author of that page), IE10 does not need `overflow-scrolling: touch`.

Which is fortunate, because IE10 doesn't support it, and I can't see it being easy to polyfill it.

Comment: Nice suggestion. In that page The author said IE9 have bad scrolling quality and it needs webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch. how to achieve this?

Comment: Sorry, but I think with IE9, you'd just have to live with it. But the question was asking about IE10 which does have good scrolling, so hopefully that's sufficient for you. (in any case, there aren't so many mobile devices with IE9; it's mainly IE10)